# Azure Logic app not reading all columns of Sharepoint list

Tags: sharepoint, azure-logic-apps

We have a logic app that reads from the Sharepoint list. The issue is SharePoint list has 170 columns whereas the logic app only reads 105 columns consistently. I had an issue with fewer rows being read from the SharePoint list as well(99 vs 546). I got around that issue by specifying the "Top Count" parameter in 'Get Items' action of Sharepoint. Wondering if there is a workaround to read all columns. I have already tried pagination option and it does not work

Answer (score 0):

You can set the limit of the columns:

[image]